# Javascript image gallery - click on image to advance to next coding

Tags: javascript, gallery, lytebox

I am trying to see if this javascript code for an image gallery as the option to click on the image to view next. Currently it is only set to go to the next image by clicking on the next/prev buttons.  Any thoughts?

Source:
http://threepointmotors.com/lytebox.js

Example:
http://threepointmotors.com/NewsandEvents/CurrentNews/2012/smartElectricDriveCollection/tabid/226/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your page has the jQuery library included already, so it should be an easy task.

```
$('body').on('click', '#lbImage', function() { //when display image is clicked
    if ($('#lbNext2_Off').is(':hidden')) //check if it isn't the last image
        myLytebox.changeContent(myLytebox.activeSlide + 1); //move to next image
});
```